# Is it possible to continuously change voltage across polarity flip?

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, analog

The title is pretty confusing without context. My issue is that I'm trying to digitally change voltage across a component (specifically CRT deflector plates), and voltage needs to switch polarity when it reaches 0V. I have considered using a digipot with a H bridge, but I hoped that someone had a more fluid (and easier to program) solution.

Comment: Please add a schematic of your CRT driving system, and some diagrams of what signals you want to make (and preferably why). Basic question: why wouldn't you use a differential amplifier (no distinction, the +/- voltage range is continuous)?

Comment: @TimWilliams Frankly, I'm a bit of a novice, but you have inadvertently answered my question. After a bit of reading it seems that a differential amplifier is exactly what I need. I was clearly overthinking it. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a DAC with a unipolar output, you can just level-shift the DAC output (using an op-amp with bipolar supplies) and add some gain. Here R2 = R3 = 2*R1, and R4 = R6. Gain is R4/R1, As shown, with 0-3.3V DAC output, you'll get 66Vp-p across the deflection plates

For example,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDpRcN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For

DAC output of 0V, Va = -16.5V and Vb = +16.5V

DAC output of 1.65V, Va = 0V and Vb = 0V

DAC output of 3.3V, Va = +16.5V and Vb = -16.5V